# Control position of RecyclerView item in StaggeredGridLayoutManager

Tags: android

I am using a StaggeredGridLayoutManager with two columns on a RecyclerView with heterogenous/multiple layouts to achieve layout like that of Snapchat discover feature.

I have overridden getItemViewType(int position) method for selecting layout file.
Here is the code.

```
public int getItemCount() {
        return this.mThumbnailDTOList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {

        if(position % 2 == 0){
            return LAYOUT1;
        }
        else if(position % 2 != 0){
            return LAYOUT2;
        }
        return -1;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder;
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext());

        switch (viewType) {
            case LAYOUT1:
                View v1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.homepage_left_column_viewholder, viewGroup, false);
                viewHolder = new LeftColumnViewHolder(v1);
                break;
            case LAYOUT2:
                View v2 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.homepage_right_column_viewholder, viewGroup, false);
                viewHolder = new RightColumnViewHolder(v2);
                break;
            default:
                View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.homepage_left_column_viewholder, viewGroup, false);
                viewHolder = new LeftColumnViewHolder(v);
                break;
        }

        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
        switch (viewHolder.getItemViewType()) {
            case LAYOUT1:
                LeftColumnViewHolder vh1 = (LeftColumnViewHolder) viewHolder;
                configureLeftColumnViewHolder(vh1, position);
                break;
            case LAYOUT2:
                RightColumnViewHolder vh2 = (RightColumnViewHolder) viewHolder;
                configureRightColumnViewHolder(vh2, position);
                break;
            default:
                LeftColumnViewHolder vh = (LeftColumnViewHolder) viewHolder;
                configureLeftColumnViewHolder(vh, position);
                break;
        }
    }
```

The effect I want is all cardviews which are odd numbered should appear in 2nd column and all even numbered cardviews should appear in first column.

Here is an image of what I have achieved.

[image: Snachat discover like grid]

Problem is the 11th position despite being odd numbered appears in first column.
What can I do to make sure that all odd/even numbered views appear in 2nd/1st column respectively

Comment: Did you solve the problem finally?

Comment: No. We decided to go for all cards identical. If you wish to achieve that, you can do so by overriding LayoutManager I suppose.

Comment: thx. you are right, i modify getNextSpan in StaggeredGridLayoutManager ,and i solve it .

Comment: @jiong103, could you please show an example of how you achieved this ?